# Improving the code by minimizing number of iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have an exercise that I did good, but I'm searching for improvement.

In my code I'm using nested loop, I want to make it 1 loop, but I cannot reach the goal.

```
def main(l1):
    newlist = []
    numbers= max(l1) + 1
    for i in range(0,numbers):
        counter = 0
        for number in l1:
            if number >= i:
                counter += 1
        newlist.append(counter)
    print(newlist)

l1=[1,5,4,3,7,8,9]
main(l1)
```

it returns `[7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1]` 10 index (max value of l1 +1)

the goal of the exercise is find the max value in l1 and then test each number in range(0,maximumnumber+1) ,

comparing the each number in l1 to number in the range (if(number >= number in the range)) and count how many times the number number in l1 is bigger equal to the number of range.

I hope it's some how clear, it is more clear by code

Comment: You can optimize by sorting elements in the the source list. Then on each iteration you will know how many elements are greater or equal than `i`.

Comment: again sorting will have inside loop for sorting purpose

Comment: Sorting is O(NlogN) which is better than current O(N^2)

Comment: @soon for this case you can even go to O(N) with the pigeon hole sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the time by using sort (as @soon said in the comment).

Sort the input list and then only loop on all number and check current position.

Consider the following code:

```
def improvedTime(l):
    l.sort() # this take O(nlogn) when n in the length of l
    cnt = 0
    ans = []
    for i in range(0, l[-1]+1): # last index in the ordered list is the max element
        while (i > l[cnt] and cnt < len(l)): #until you reach bigger element
            cnt = cnt + 1
        ans.append(len(l) - cnt)
    print(ans)

l1 = [1,5,4,3,7,8,9]
l2 = [2,9,7,5,3,8,7]
improvedTime(l1)
improvedTime(l2)
```

Output is:

```
[7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1]
```

Complexity is O(max(n+m, nlogn) when `n` is list size and `m` is the max element.

Notice that you also have to loop till the max element anyway - which can be worse when having input of `[3,7,150000]` -> you can also improve this little bit but my answer should fix your case.

This is the way suggested by @LieRyan: (I will explain step by step)

```
def a(l):
    ansSize = max(l) +1 # calculate the size of the output array 
    ans = [0] * (ansSize) # init the output array with zeros
    for i in l:
        ans[i] += 1 # count and mark every element from the input array and add to ans array
                    # according our example here ans = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1]
    total = 0 # reset var to calculate accumulate sum
    for i in range(-1, -ansSize -1, -1): #loop the output array from the end to start
        total += ans[i] # save new total by adding all previous with current element (accumulate sum)
        ans[i] = total # set current i-index-position with total

    print(ans) # out put is: [7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1]

l2 = [2,9,7,5,3,8,7]
a(l2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much David, I couldn't even think in this way, could you please give some suggestion, or a good way to study, I just started Python.

Comment: I am not a python expert - I guess you can find many tutorials on youTube. This question is more algorithm question. If it help you please mark it as a accept

Comment: I have a little problem, if I put a list [2,9,7,5,3,8,7] it gives [7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2], but It should be [7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1]

Thank you again :)

Comment: @LordNord This happens because you have `7` twice. I update the answer to support this case also

Comment: Thank you for your help and support, I have a test file of the problem it still give me an error :(  I even don't know where is the error.
The solution of @Lie Ryan works pefect, BUT I don't understand the algorithm

Comment: @LordNord I tried to explain @ Lie Ryan solution (which is better then mine) in my updated answer. Hope now it more understandable

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty simple improvement:

```
from itertools import accumulate
def one(l1):
    counts = [0] * (max(l1) + 1)
    for n in l1:
        counts[-n - 1] += 1
    return list(accumulate(counts))[::-1]
```

---

This version is much more complicated, but does everything in just two passes, which I believe is the minimum for this problem:

```
def two(l1):
    counts = []
    for n in l1:
        try:
            counts[n] += 1
        except IndexError:
            counts.extend([0] * (n - len(counts)) + [1])

    total = counts[-1]
    for i in range(-2, -len(counts) - 1, -1):
        total += counts[i]
        counts[i] = total

    return counts
```

---

Both solutions are O(n) and amortized O(n) respectively.

You could modify the second solution to become O(n) by preallocating the list, but that will come at a tradeoff of needing three passes over the list.

---

The basic idea of the two solutions above is that you first do a [counting sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), and then do a [running sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) from the back of the list.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not allowed to use libraries , I forgot to notice it.
but any way, I should first learn those function like try and except, you open my eyes for something new that I should study